# Add a new property to an object stored with scriptDB

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a database (scriptDB) and have stored information (more than 40 properties of about 600 people-students-).

```
var obj = {

alumne_id: email,

alumne_ordre: nomsencer_ordre,

alumne_timestamp: {created: new Date (). getTime (), changed:'', editor: 'unedited'},

alumne_nom: {nom: nomREAD, cognom1: cognom1READ, cognom2: cognom2READ, cognoms: cognomsREAD, nomsencer: nomsencerREAD},

(...)

}
```

I stored this object in my database:

```
var stored = db.save(ob);
```

I defined thus, properties of objects and have my stored. This works perfectly and update data, for example, change "alumne_nom.nom" to a new value: 'Joana'

Now I want to add new properties to all or some of these objects (students).

The problem is that I can add a property as

```
newproperty1
```

with:

```
stored.newproperty1 = '50 '
```

But I can not do:

```
stored.newproperty1.sub1

stored.newproperty1.sub2

stored.newproperty1.sub3
```

Does anyone know how I can add these subproperties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add "subproperties" you need to first define the property. You can do it by setting an empty object to it, e.g.

```js
stored.newproperty1 = {};
//then all subs should work
stored.newproperty1.sub1 = 10;
```

You could already pass the subs definitions on the braces as you do with the object as well:

```
stored.newproperty1 = {sub1:10, sub2:20, etc:'value'};
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Henrique (muito obrigado)

Comment: @sergicurtu You're welcome. Since you're new here, you should mark an answer as accepted when you feel you got a good one. Another Stackoverflow's nice feature is voting ;)